# C++ struct, public data members and inheritance

Tags: c++, class

Is it ok to have public data members in a C++ class/struct in certain particular situations?
How would that go along with inheritance? 
I've read opinions on the matter, some stated already here

[practices on when to implement accessors on private member variables rather than making them public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952907/practices-on-when-to-implement-accessors-on-private-member-variables-rather-than)
[Accessors vs. public members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670958/accessors-vs-public-members)

or in books/articles (Stroustrup, Meyers) but I'm still a little bit in the shade.

I have some configuration blocks that I read from a file (integers, bools, floats) and 
I need to place them into a structure for later use. I don't want to expose these externally just use them inside another class (I actually do want to pass these  config parameters to another class but don't want to expose them through a public API).

The fact is that I have many such config parameters (15 or so) and writing getters and setters seems an unnecessary overhead. Also I have more than one configuration block and these are sharing some of the parameters. Making a struct with all the data members public and then subclassing does not feel right. What's the best way to tackle that situation? 
Does making a big struct to cover all parameters provide an acceptable compromise (I 
would have to leave some of these set to their default values for blocks that do not use them)?

Comment: Put them in a map and access them by name using a string.

Comment: @Neil: how would I do that? The parameters do not have the same type. They can be float, integer, string, boolean. I would have to keep a map for every type of parameter: std::map<std::string, int>, std::map<std::string, float> etc. ... unless I'm missing something

Comment: A type such as ParamValue, which stores the parameters as strings and provides four accessor functions that do the conversions would seem to be the way to go. With your design, every time you add a new parameter, you will have to edit your code and recompile.

Comment: @Maruis - correct. You could make the map store values of type `boost::any`, but then you'd have to `any_cast` the value back out to the correct type each time you needed it. Although these dynamic approaches reduce maintenance on the config class, they make static checking less capable (i.e. compile-time checking that you store/retrieve the right types).

Comment: @Neil, @Daniel: I think I will try the map with boost::any solution and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a data structure that isn't intended to have behaviour but genuinely is nothing more than a pure `struct` in the C sense, particularly if each instance of it is only used internally to the implementation of other "proper" classes, then it is fine to make it a `struct` and have public fields. After all, as you've pointed out, once you've given it get/set accessor functions for every field then you're back to the logical equivalent of public data anyway.

Comment: That's what I thought in the first place but then ... how would I handle the difference between configuration blocks? Through inheritance or just make another plain struct? 
The blocks do share some data.

Comment: A struct can have another struct as a member, so you can "include" them inside one another in that way. This has the advantage (over inheritance) that you won't ever get name clashes.

Comment: Daniel, I disagree (and so does Scott Meyers, if that has more weight). There’s a long shot between public fields and public accessors when it comes to encapsulation. In particular, the latter are future-proof and changing the internal logic will (probably) not mangle the interface, nor introduce binary incompatibility. Changing fields, on the other hand, *always* will.

Comment: @Konrad, you may have missed "if each instance of it is only used internally to the implementation of other "proper" classes". It's quite common for the internals of some well-defined class to make use of a struct, e.g. a COW string class might internally use a struct for the shared data. Clients of the class have no idea this is happening, so it's fine. As for binary compatibility, I can't see much point using C++ at all across that boundary, except in some carefully limited form, due to name mangling (merely changing compiler versions would potentially break binary compatibility).

Comment: yes, I missed that. As for binary compatibility, that’s mainly useful because you don’t need to recompile object files unnecessarily. In large projects, this may be a *huge* factor to consider, since C++ compiles so **darn** slowly.

Answer (score 3):

I usually write my program config files using Google's protocol buffers.  The getters and setters (among many other useful functions) are generated for you, similar to a struct.  It also makes editing your config files trivial, allowing for obvious field naming and grouping.

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/

Comment: Wouldn't fit my situation but an interesting link nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

If the class you want accessing the internals inherits from your main class, setting things `protected` will do what you like.  If you want another unrelated class to have access you have to make them `friend`s.

Comment: `protected` fields are (almost?) as bad as `public` fields.

Comment: I'm not recommending the practice.  Just telling the OP how to get done what he says he wants to get done.

`friend`ing is even worse, IMO.  ;)

Comment: No, that’s a misconception. Usage of `friend` is completely fine, since it doesn’t violate encapsulation, as opposed to `protected` and `public`. With `friend`, you as the writer of the class exclusively control who gets access to the internals. With `protected`, you completely give that control up.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  On the other hand friends can fondle your privates.  It seems friendship is very libertine in C++.  I'd prefer a bit finer-grained control than all-or-nothing.

Comment: It seems that in C++ or life, giving friends access to your privates leads to unforeseen consequences.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to make these members `protected` - that way they can be accessed by derived classes but are not public.

Comment: `protected` fields are (almost?) as bad as `public` fields.

Comment: Ok we get it Konrad, you don't like protected fields. :) Saying that public or protected fields are always bad seems a little obtuse don't you think? I mean if they were bad in all situations, why don't we just get rid of them altogether. I think using them wisely based on your context is probably ok.